# void pointer and its assignment to the void datatype

Tags: c, pointers

The problem is using void datatype and assigning some value to the void variable.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 void *pVoid;
 pVoid = (void*)0;
 printf("%lu",sizeof(pVoid));
 return 0;
}
```

what is assigned to pVoid in second line.

Comment: Is is assigned the `NULL` pointer value. Aside: the format specifier to use with `sizeof` is `%zu`.

Comment: _what is assigned to pVoid in second line. ?_ Its `NULL`. Side note, in standard C library, `NULL` is defined as `(void*)0`.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/128447/30872

Answer (score 2):

Copied directly from the [standard library wiki](https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_standard_library:stdlib.h:NULL):

> Defined in stddef.h, locale.h, stdio.h, stdlib.h, string.h,
>   time.h.
>
> In standard C, this can be implemented as:
>
> ```
> #if !defined(NULL)
>     #define NULL ((void*)0)
> #endif
> ```

So `pVoid` get assigned exactly what it would get assigned with `NULL` on the second line.

**Edit**: as mentioned by @Jens Gustedt in comments, it is good to note that this implementation of `NULL` is not unique, and can be platform-dependent.

Comment: This is only one possible implementation of `NULL`, unfortunately.

Comment: Could you develop ? Including `stdlib.h` at the top of all my `.c` files has become such a reflex that I don't know of any other definition, I'd like to learn something.

Comment: Yes, this is what you are supposed to use. The defintion in the C standard is just a null pointer constant. Other values that are commonly used are `0` or `0L`, for example. Only because your platform uses a certain value, doesn't mean that other platforms have to use the same.

Answer (score 1):

`pVoid` is assigned the value `NULL`.  This is because the expression `(void*)0` is defined as a **null pointer constant**.

Section 6.3.2.3p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states:

> An  integer  constant  expression  with  the  value  0,  or  such  an 
>   expression  cast  to  type `void *` , is called a *null pointer constant*
>   .  If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the
>   resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare
>   unequal to a pointer to any object or function.